# Select in select Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have 4 tables. Users, Articles, Langs, LangList

**Articles table:** ..., uid (Users.id), lang (Langs.id),...

**LangList table:** id, uid (Users.id), langid (Langs.id)

I want to select all those articles for a specified user (ex. Users.id = 66), where are in his selected languages list.

***If i make this:***

```
function FindActiveLangs($lang){
    $sql ="SELECT langid FROM LangList WHERE `uid`= '66' AND `active`='1';";
    $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
    $lang_string = " ( ".$lang."lang = '0' ";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)){
        $lang_string .= " OR ".$lang."lang = '".$row['langid']."' ";
    }
    $lang_string .= " ) ";
    return $lang_string;
} //end of FindActiveLangs


$tables = " Articles ";
$lang_string = FindActiveLangs("Articles.");
$where1 = "WHERE ".$lang_string." ";
$sql = "select distinct Articles.id, title, descr, thumb, relDate, 
            Articles.alias, Articles.lang, author, source  
        from ".$tables.$where1." and Users";
```

I took the results in 0.01-0.03 secs

***In the second way, that I think is better for clean code:***

```
$sql = "select distinct Articles.id, title, descr, thumb, relDate, 
            Articles.alias, Articles.lang, author, source  
        from Articles 
        where lang IN 
            (SELECT langid FROM LangList WHERE uid= '66' AND active='1')";
```

I took the results in 1.1-1.3 secs

Is there any way to execute this query, with second way with better performance? the "IN" kills the speed

Thanks in advance...

Comment: There is no join between Articles and TagsList. I don't use MySql, but it seems to me that it would produce a cross join. Also, I don't see any columns from TagsList being used.

Comment: I forgot to delete TagsList, this query is more advanced than this and I rewrote it only for the problem that i have, sorry now it is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) instead of IN. The performance is much better.

```
select distinct Articles.id, title, descr, thumb, relDate, Articles.alias, Articles.lang, author, source  
from Articles, TagsList 
where
    Articles.lang = 0 OR 
    EXISTS 
          (SELECT *
           FROM LangList 
           WHERE uid= '66' AND active='1' 
           AND langid = Articles.lang)
```

EDIT: second attempt (check if the performance is any better):

```
SELECT Articles.*
   FROM Articles 
    INNER JOIN LangList
        ON langid = Articles.lang
   WHERE uid= '66' AND active='1' 

UNION

SELECT Articles.*
FROM Articles
WHERE 
Articles.lang=0
AND
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
           FROM LangList 
           WHERE uid= '66' AND active='1' 
           AND langid = Articles.lang
)
```

Comment: Perfect. 

Now for optimization reasons, the default language is English that is the id=0. 
So i dont want to store it as row for every user in LangList table. LangList table has only the extra languages, for example Langs.id = 1 (French), Langs.id=2 (German). 
So how i can modify your query to accept only extra languages and the English Articles.lang=0 by default?

Comment: I found it:

select distinct Articles.id, title, descr, thumb, relDate, Articles.alias, Articles.lang, author, source from Articles, TagsList where EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LangList WHERE uid= '66' AND active='1' AND langid = Articles.lang) or Articles.lang=0 order by relDate DESC

Comment: @kokazani: I'm not sure if I understand correctly how the tables work, but you may try with a OR as in my revised answer

Comment: @kokazani: oops... looks like you were quicker than me... :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the response time now is 1.9 secs :(

The concept is that we upload Articles, usually in English, but sometimes in other languages. All Users have the option to add more languages at their settings to view articles in all languages not only English articles. So LangList table is used for extra langs storage, only. If user hasn't selected any extra lang, only English articles are shown (this make us for optimization reasons dont add rows for English language (langid=0) in LangList table)

Comment: @kokazani : I added a second method. I can't test it though... the gist of it is: the inner join takes all articles where there's a language (other than english) in LangList. The UNION should add the remaining ones (where there is an english version and no corresponding rows in LangList)

Comment: N1 @paolo-falabella !! 1st query took 0.0657 sec, and second one 0.1100 sec (PERFECT). Really thanks paolo!